# How can I know the people following me just use multiple cars but not a GPS tracker?

Tags: security, privacy

Dealing with a **very toxic** situation, I am listened/spied on by my neighbor and his friend and they follow me as soon as I leave my home, be it on foot or by car.

Is there a trick I can use to determine if they are just using multiple cars to follow me (doing it professionally like cops maybe) or if they have planted a GPS tracker, either permanently inside the car or just stuck underneath it?

I bought a RF detector [like this one](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Professional-G318-1Mhz-8000Mhz-Wireless-RF-Signal-Detector-Tap-Detect-Mobile/112157437998?epid=2261039752&hash=item1a1d1ab02e:g:rQQAAOSwvutayRhv) but this has been ineffective for various reasons:

- It is catching background RF noise.
- I am driving alone, so I can't sweep the car while driving.
- The tracker could send location either every 5 minutes or only on demand (via SMS).
  So this solution is not working.

I have caught them following me 3 times (by luck maybe), but I just wonder if they are trying to make me believe they follow me by car to make me stop looking inside the car for the tracker, if there is one.

I know for sure that I have been followed because if I rent a hotel room I spend the night awake because they prevent me from sleeping by renting the room next door and making small noises loud enough to awake me. So this costs me 50€ every time for nothing.

Or if they dare to show their faces in front of me.

Comment: Have you spoken to a doctor (psychiatrist or psychologist) to verify you aren't just paranoid?

Comment: change the vehicle you are travelling in, if they still follow you, there isn't much more you can do.

Comment: @ZeissIkon it really helps when you are alone and helpless and trying to talk about the deep **** you are in and people throw at your face that you are mad. I feel even more isolated and alone each time. You are helping "them" not me by doing that. And this is their strategy, to isolate me even more.

Comment: This is genuinely a question Lifehacks can't help with -- it's either a matter of spycraft (very unlikely, unless you work in the intelligence community) or a psychological issue (far, far more common).  If you aren't trained in spycraft, working on the cutting edge of some science or technology, or privy to genuine government secrets, there's no reason anyone would want/need to follow you.  That leaves one option.  I'm not throwing it in your face, I'm trying to suggest help we can't give.

Comment: Do you have/carry a mobile device? Lose it! Get yourself off the grid. Enjoy: https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2019/12/20/opinion/location-data-national-security.html

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to check for GPS trackers:

1. take your car to a garage, have them put the car on a lift.
2. Inspect the underside, look for small rectangular boxes. An [internet search](https://www.ebay.com/bhp/mini-gps-tracker?rmvSB=true) gives you an idea of what to look for.

It's very unlikely a tracker will be inside the car, because its battery has to be charged every few weeks, and breaking into your car every two weeks is too likely to get noticed. So if they use one, it'll be underneath.

If they're following you, they'll only use the cars they own. Adding rentals is way over the top just for harrassment. So find out which cars they own, learn to recognize them and look for them.

Your daily routine is predictable. If you go to work every day, they don't need to follow you to guess where you are.

I suspect the best way to deal with this is to not let them get on your nerves. Ignore them.

If they start doing more than following you, that's the time to involve the police.

Answer (score 9):

With all due respect,

## There's no one following you at all.

There's no GPS. There's no 'professional multicar tracking system'. They're not in your cell phone, assuming you have one.

> I know for sure that I have been followed because if I rent a hotel room I spend the night awake because they prevent me from sleeping by renting the room next door and making small noises loud enough to awake me...
>
> You are helping "them" not me by doing that. And this is their strategy, to isolate me even more.

**Unless you are legitimately a former spy** (in which case you wouldn't be asking strangers on the open internet for how to sweep your own car for bugs), ***no one* is playing these kind of gaslighting psy ops on you**. Not family, not business acquaintances, and certainly not your neighbors or their friends. Angry neighbors or loan sharks might follow someone to yell at them or threaten them; they don't rent adjacent hotel rooms to keep their victims awake with low-volume chatter.

Your certainty that this is occurring in this manner just means that you are placing yourself and innocent members of the public at risk by not talking to a mental health worker and getting the medication that you very much need.

Don't spend any money hoisting your car; don't buy sweeping devices; don't tow your car across town; don't rent sets of hotel rooms to guard your flanks. Find someone in social services or psychology that you can talk to instead; there's even a [Psychology Stack](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/) here where you can get advice about who to talk to. Some I've met are even be kind enough to take cash for sessions and keep minimal paperwork, if you're very concerned it could fall into the wrong hands or cause trouble. You deserve it, and good people like yourself should do what they can to protect those around them.

Comment: You obviously don't know anything about the situation because I have the time nor the place to share every detail of everything that happened in the last 2 years.

Comment: **When you don't know anything**, please refrain yourself from making quick mental judgement on people or on things. Making general assessment is not helping either. Yes most of the time, when people talk about being followed they may have a problem. But not every time. Sometimes they are being followed. When a girl talks about sexual harassment do you tell her she's crazy or do you help her ?

Comment: @EA34ffg6 **Seriously**. Please. You aren't interested in listening to me but talk to someone you do trust, ideally a professional. There are community mental health centers—which should be cheap or free in most of Europe—who can help you and help you protect the people around you as you deal with this. I wish you all the best.

Comment: Again, it's been a month and nothing has happened to you. Unless you are in a cutting-edge technological field, politics, or intelligence,—in which case you should be appealing to "your side" for help and not posting their secrets online—there is no one after you and your certainty that there is should tell you that something has gone wrong and you need medical help to think clearly again. Godspeed, friendo.

Comment: @EA34ffg6 whether it's real or not doesn't change the fact that this is obviously taking a toll on you. Psychologists can be of great help to the people being harassed, I'd suggest going to see one to help you deal with the stress and trauma this is causing you. It could greatly improve your quality of life.

Comment: I have seen a psychologist that seemed convinced by my speech and did not feel the need for me to come back. She thought that I might need more help from law enforcement. But I don't think that's an option. Because 1. I will not be believed. 2. I have no proof. 3. Those people are not breaking the law. Unless they publish things or something else.

Comment: Gaslighting only happens to spies??

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of many ways to *prove* there is **no GPS** on your car. But you can easily show that they are monitoring you in ways other than a GPS (Which doesn't imply there is no GPS, just that it's less likely), you can also prove that they have a GPS, but it may not tell you where it is on the car.

**To prove that they are looking at you**:

**Take a taxi** one morning. The taxi will be GPS-free.

If they are able to find you on the first morning, it's because they're looking at you leave your home and follow you from there. It doesn't prove there is no GPS but it proves they're monitoring you directly (not just via a GPS app)

**To prove there is a GPS**:

**Find the GPS: Hoist your car up on a car lift**, just go to the mechanic's shop and ask if they can lift it for you to look. If you find one, then you can remove it. But remember that if you don't find it it's still not *certain* that there is nothing... you may simply have not found it.

**If you don't find the GPS and are still fairly sure that there is one, here's how you can prove they have a GPS:** Have your car towed somewhere, maybe to the other end of the city, and ask a friend to check if specific cars (of the people spying on you) turn up. If they were only following you visually, they wouldn't follow a tow truck but if they were relying on a GPS then they would go have a look at the (empty) car.

Whichever way you choose to go, definitely contact the police about this, and perhaps a psychologist to help you deal with the stress and trauma this is causing you.

Comment: Come on, everybody knows the taxi drivers have been suborned too. Don't you ever watch James Bond films? And if they get the taxi drivers, surely the mechanics as well?

Answer (score 3):

I propose that you **work with someone** to **double your resources** and disorient anyone else who might be interested in causing you to be unhappy.

Keeping you isolated is something *they* want. Working with a professional will throw them off-course and make their continued espionage impossible.

I have visited a building where medical professionals have their offices and while in various waiting rooms I've noticed that there has been special equipment installed. Since then, I've noticed the same types of things in other similar medical office buildings. Things like **white-noise generators** are *common* to prevent eaves-dropping or listening in. The places are private so anyone who doesn't have an appointment for meeting their doctor is obvious. The buildings are heavy and well-made to prevent snooping. All the doors are secure. Medical professionals are well-trained in both privacy and security issues. Lastly, Each medical professional is a member of their professional order AND city, district, and federal governments (a trust issue). Lastly, they're smart, intelligent, and with more resources than you alone have. You can discreetly pick and choose your team member.

Teamwork!